# Converting gets() string into an integer in C

Tags: c, gets

I am trying to write code that reads a string of numbers using `gets()` and then converts said string into an integer. However something is going wrong with my conversion and I can't figure out what.
I also have to use `gets()` to do this.
If anyone can see whats wrong or knows a better way to do this please help.

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
   char s[1000];
   int n = 0;
   printf("Input the number you wish to have converted\n");//asks the user to enter the number they want converted
   gets(s);//reads the input

   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
      char temp = s[i] - '0';
      n = n + pow(10, length - i - 1) * temp;//converts from a character array to an integer for decimal to binary conversion
   }
}
```

Comment: `length` is neither declared nor initialized.

Comment: Why not simply use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)?

Comment: use atoi function to convert from string to integer

Comment: OT: Do not use `gets()` as it does not provide any way to avoid buffer overflows. Use `fgets()` instead. `gets()` isn't even part of C anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using your own method to do this, there are a number of utilities in the standard library. Take a look at `strol` and `sscanf`. It's also wise to use `fgets` instead of `gets` as pointed out in the comments above.

### **Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char s[1000];
    int n = 0;
    printf("Input the number you wish to have converted\n");//asks the user to enter the number they want converted
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);//reads the input

    n = (int)strol(s, NULL, 10);
    printf("Number from strol: %d\n", n);

    sscanf(s, "%d", &n);
    printf("Number from sscanf: %d\n", n);
}
```

You can even bypass `fgets` and use `scanf` if you don't want to keep the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Number from scanf: %d\n", n);
}
```

Comment: The use of `strtol()` is preferred over `atoi()`, as `atoi()` does not provide usefull error checking.